# Confusion regarding simple pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

The Time Period of simple pendulum is given b:-

$T~=~2π\sqrt{\frac{Lθ}{g\sinθ}}$

In order to derive this expression, I have to assume:-

$X = Lθ$,

$X$ means the displacement.

I also did certain experiments using a stopwatch and a pendulum made up of a strong rope, a metallic bob (mass of rope is negligible as compared to bob); to find that that the expression of time period is true for all cases and thus, displacement must always equal $Lθ$.

However, some sources state that the expression for displacement is inaccurate.

Who is wrong- the sources or me?

Comment: The period formula for arbitrary amplitude can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period).

Comment: List the sources, and perhaps explain how you are doing the experiments

Comment: Hi, I've gone through some of the questions on your account, and it seems to me, that almost all of them begin with "confusion regarding xyz". I suggest not to use these type of titles as they reduce the searchabilith of questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$T~=~2π\sqrt{\frac{Lθ}{g\sinθ}}$$
doesn't make sense, the period shouldn't depend on the displacement, which is changing over the course of the motion. The usual expression for small displacements is
$$T\approx2π\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}.$$

The horizontal displacement is $L \sin\theta$, which you can see by drawing the pendulum and considering the right triangle with the string as the hypotenuse and with the other sides in the horizontal and vertical directions. For small angles $\theta$, $L\sin \theta\approx L \theta$, so the period is given approximately by the second expression above.

Alternatively, you can define the displacement as the length of the circular arc that connects bob to the equilibrium point, in which case the displacement is exactly $L\theta$. However, the restoring force along this arc is $-mg \sin\theta$, which again only simplifies to $-mg \theta$ for small $|\theta|$, and this simplification is required to derive the second expression above.

Comment: That is the distance that the bob must travel along its circular trajectory to get to the equilibrium point, for any angle. It is not a horizontal displacement.

Comment: The equation of motion for any angle is $$\ddot \theta + \frac{g}{L}\sin \theta=0.$$ This doesn't look like your equation, and what is $a$?

Comment: The equation of motion doesn't depend on what formulation you use, you will get the same equation if you (correctly) use Newtonian mechanics. I would recommend taking a look at the Wikipedia article posted in comments above. I don't think you can get your equation by rearranging mine since mine contains $\sin \theta$, not $\theta$. As for $a$, the important question is "which acceleration?". Horizontal, or tangential?

Comment: That is not descriptive enough. How do you write it as a function of $\theta$? If you use use the horizontal displacement, you need to use horizontal acceleration. If you use $L\theta$ as the displacement, you need to use tangential acceleration. Both are restoring accelerations.

Comment: Then your equation says $\ddot \theta + \omega^2\theta=0$, which is only valid for small $|\theta|$.

Comment: I don't know what $x$ means. You need to be specific about which displacement you are talking about. Please read my answer again and if anything isn't clear, ask specifically about that.

Comment: displacement = arclength = $Lθ$? For all case?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $